# How to copy paragraphs (with number formatting) and images from Words (.docx) and paste into Excel (.xlsx) using Python

Tags: python, excel, ms-word, copy-paste

I have contract clauses in Words (.docx) format that needs to be frequently copy and pasted into Excel (.xlsx) to be sent to the third party. The clauses are often updated hence there's always a need to copy and paste these clauses over. I only need to copy and paste all the paragraphs and images **after** the contents page. Here is a sample of the [Clause document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZzV29R6y2q0oU3HAVrqsFa158OhvpxEK).

I have tried doing up a code using Python to achieve this outcome. 
Here is the code that I have done so far:

```
!pip install python-docx
import docx
import xlsxwriter

document = docx.Document("Clauses Sample.docx")
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxx/clauses sample.xlsx')

docText = []
index_row = 0
Sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet("Sheetttt")

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.text:
        docText.append(paragraph.text)
        xx = '\n'.join(docText)

        Sheet1.write(index_row,0, xx)

        index_row = index_row+1

wb.close()        
#print(xx)
```

However, my Excel file output looks like this:

[image]

But I want my Excel output to look something like these for example:
[image] [image]

Is there any way that I can get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two problems (and solutions) that I think would help get you closer.

1. Your `docText` variable is accumulating **all** the text from the document.  I think what you meant is to write out one paragraph per row of the spreadsheet. I would change the `for` loop to look like this:

```py
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.text:
        # Put paragraph.text into the row, NOT docText.
        # Do you really need the join()?  I don't think so.
        Sheet1.write(index_row,0, paragraph.text)

        index_row = index_row+1
```

2. You're dropping blank paragraphs with the `if paragraph.text:` test.  If you want empty rows (shown as rows 4 and 15 in your spreadsheet example), take out that `if` test.

Comment: Hey Rusty Widebottom! You're right, the output is what i want now :) But is there any way that I can copy and paste the images in along with the paragraphs as well?

Comment: Definitely there's a way.  There is some good example code in this article https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/bwlszb/extracting_figure_from_docx_file_with_python/ that shows how use `docx` to access and save the image.  To put it in the spreadsheet, the `xlsxwriter` module has a `insert_image()` function - see https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/ - the example on the front page shows how.  Good luck!